# Procedure to delete all rows in a column older than 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

Can anyone please help me
to write a procedure/function to delete the rows older than 30days from a column named
`prs_date` from all tables in my database in mysql?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why din't you succeed? it doesn't seem that hard to be honest....

Comment: Does that keep you from googling? If you google on your title you will be able to make the query in the answers with the first 2 links by yourself. So then you would already have something instead of nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) operator and combine it with [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), prs_date) > 30;
```

Comment: here i have to select a particular column from all tables

Comment: Oh. Sorry missed the part with `all tables`.

Comment: @Marcus there would be many tables, so that its difficult to search n write each and every table name, so iam asking for a function or procedure.

Comment: i hope its easy with creating a procedure

Comment: Is it OK to manually specify each table that contains a prs_date? Else it can get kind of complex.

Answer (score 0):

this query can help

```
DELETE FROM sometable WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(prs_date) <= 30;
```

Comment: i need to write a procedure/function

Comment: it deletes, but i need it for all tables in my database which consists the column prs_date